# What order will increase the security level of the system?

Tags: encryption, compression

I have seen multiple sources stating that compressing before encrypting is the best way to increase security.

But what I am curious is that if you compress, encrypt and than compress again, does it provide better security, or does it not matter?

I do not care about efficiency, just the security.

Comment: Except for already weak encryption systems or modes, compression does very little to nothing to increase security. Also, except for weak systems or modes (like ECB), compressing *after* encryption will not achieve any effect; there's no redundancy detectable in ciphertext to allow compression algorithms to make the output smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Compression after encryption is pointless, since it won't compress. Encrypted data is indistinguishable from random data to the compressor, so the result will be very slightly expanded instead of compressed.